# Importing Another Cocos2d Project's Classes, Code, and SRC

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

The project I was toying around with for some reason was a dated version of cocos2d, and the classes and methods I was trying to introduce were too recent. So, I have successfully installed the new cocos2d, and have created a cocos2d template in Xcode. My issue is that this project is brand new, and I want to bring all my other project's code into this.

I have searched this across other stackoverflow threads, and just dragged the files/folder into the new project. When the files wouldn't transfer, I adjusted their path, and then dragged them in, or in one unique case, when dealing with the class main.m, I just changed its internal code so that it would sync up with the rest of the code.

However, because this is a template file, there are some extra baggage classes that I am not sure how to handle. These classes are the classes that come standard in the 'Classes' folder when the cocos2d template is first created:

```
GameConfig.h
HelloWorldLayer.h
HelloWorldLayer.m
RootViewController.h
RootViewController.m
MyGameAppDelegate.h
MyGameAppDelegate.m
```

And then in the 'Other Sources' folder:
MyGame_Prefix.pch

These classes or their likeness does not appear to be used in the original project from which I copied the other classes, is there any special use for them that would be dangerously stupid for me to delete them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete HelloWorldLayer. It's just the example scene/layer.

You would do well to leave the other files in. Any modifications you may have made to your old project's app delegate (such as which scene is passed to CCDirector's runWithScene method) should be re-done in the MyGameAppDelegate rather than replacing that with your old project's app delegate.

The reason is that the startup sequence for cocos2d has changed to support Retina devices, autorotation, changes in the iOS SDK, etc. The RootViewController handles autorotation, should you need that. Whether autorotation is enabled or not can be changed via GameConfig.h.